# Put TextView on right bottom corner

Tags: android, layout, textview, coordinates, android-relativelayout

I need to put a textView on the right bottom corner of the layout and I don't know how to do it without absoluteX and absoluteY coords.

I put the code below and also a screen capture:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.prodintec.am_motion.QuizActivity">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="368dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp">

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:paddingEnd="10dp"
        android:paddingStart="10dp">

        <TableRow
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/HeaderTextView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="FOUR OPTIONS QUESTION" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/answer1"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                android:paddingRight="20dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                android:background="@color/primary"
                android:textColor="@color/accent"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:text="ANSWER 1" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/answer2"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                android:paddingRight="20dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                android:background="@color/primary"
                android:textColor="@color/accent"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:text="ANSWER 2" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/answer3"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                android:paddingRight="20dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                android:background="@color/primary"
                android:textColor="@color/accent"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:text="ANSWER 3" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/answer4"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                android:paddingRight="20dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                android:background="@color/primary"
                android:textColor="@color/accent"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:text="ANSWER 4" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/HeaderTextView2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="TWO OPTIONS QUESTION" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/answer5"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                android:paddingRight="20dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                android:background="@color/primary"
                android:textColor="@color/accent"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:text="ANSWER 1" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/answer6"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                android:paddingRight="20dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                android:background="@color/primary"
                android:textColor="@color/accent"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:text="ANSWER 2" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/PointsTextView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="POINTS:" />
</RelativeLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

Can anyone help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Points `TextView` use the below code:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/PointsTextView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:text="POINTS:"
    android:textAlignment="textEnd" />
```

Comment: Welcome. Happy coding.

Answer (score 2):

Add this in TextView....

```
android:gravity="bottom|right"
```

Answer (score 0):

in the TextView:

```
 android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
 android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
```

this should do it.

and It's a relative layout, weight won't work with it.

Comment: This take the textview on the bottom left corner, not on the right bottom corner. Why? Thanks for the weight mistake!

Answer (score 0):

For RelativeLayout, you can read this page to know the XML attributes:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html

For your case, 
you can use 
**android:layout_alignParentBottom**
and 
**android:layout_alignParentRight**

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/PointsTextView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="POINTS:" />
```

Also,
reminder to add 
**android:layout_above** in the tablelayout, so the tablelayout will be cover the textview

```
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/PointsTextView"
    android:paddingTop="20dp"
    android:paddingEnd="10dp"
    android:paddingStart="10dp">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<TextView
  android:id="@+id/PointsTextView"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
  android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
  android:gravity="right"
  android:text="POINTS:" />
```

Comment: This take the textview on the bottom left corner, not on the right bottom corner. Why?

Comment: Or use width=wrap-content

Comment: Updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

**TextView**(which you want to put on right bottom)

so use

```
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

inside your **TextView**

and don't use

```
android:layout_weight="1"
```

because layout_weight works inside LinearLayout.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `ConstraintLayout` inside another `LayoutManager` like `RelativeLayout`.

And you're not making use of it, because you're not using the constraints to align `Views`. Here is a guide for you:

[ConstraintLayout Guide](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/constraint-layout/#0)

Finally, to align your `TextView` inside a bottom/rigth in a `RelativeLayout`, you should use :

```
 android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
 android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use framelayout to put elements on each other. [Read this](http://abhiandroid.com/ui/framelayout)